# Tensorflow/Keras find two most similar filters

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a tensorflow/keras CNN.  It has layers and some are Conv2D. In a given layer I want to efficiently find the two filters in the Conv2D that are most similar.
The layer.weights is a list of shape (height, width, depth) filter_count long.
I want to compare by the difference or maybe the sqrt(diff^2) between each element in (height,width,depth) then sum so the difference is a single float value.

If T1 is thelayer.weights[idx1] and T2 is thelayer.weights[idx2]
then the comparison is tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(T1, T2)))

I want to compare every filter to every other filter and take the 3 lowest differences. (The first one will always be zero where it T1 and T2 are the same tensor, self)

Obviously I can do nested loops but that is not functional and nifty.

Is there some built in tensorflow or keras function to do this fast and possibly in the GPU?

Answer (score 1):

Its not quite clear from your description, but I assume the shape of `weights` is [filter_count, height,width,depth]. If `filter_count` is along a different axis the arguments to "reduce_sum" will have to be modified accordingly.

You can use broadcasting to parallelize this process.

```
differences = tf.sqrt(
    tf.reduce_sum(
      tf.squared_difference(
        tf.expand_dims(thelayer.weights,0), 
        tf.expand_dims(thelayer.weights,1),

        ),
      (-1,-2,-3)
    )
)
```

This will result in a tensor of shape [filter_count, filter_count] where element `differences[i, j]` measure differences between filter weights i and j.

You can then filter to find the desired elements.